# Warning message "...strategy.close()` with a `when` parameter as the second argument" but not using when

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Pinescript now states after compiling:

> The script uses a deprecated overload of `strategy.close()` with a `when` parameter as the second argument. When calling this function with only positional arguments, use a string for the second argument to avoid unexpected results.

However, there is no `when` as second argument to the `strategy.close()` call. The warning message relates to the following lines:

```
if exit_long
    strategy.close('golong')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an workaround seen in the [PineCoders Pine Script™ Q&A](https://t.me/PineCodersOfficial)

add `immediately = true`

Something like that:

```
if exit_long
    strategy.close('golong', immediately = true)
```